# Test return statement in angular 6 using jasmine/karma

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I want to write the test case for the return statement.

```
constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }
@HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {

if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, if a function's return value is void, or returns nothing, it implicitly returns undefined. So you could test your onKeyDown function like this:

```
const event = {
    key: 1
}

expect(onKeyDown(event)).toBeUndefined()
```